# What I need to take care when encrypt a file?

Tags: file, encryption

I'm currently interesting in encrypt file. But I don't know much about what issue may occur when I convert byte-to-byte. I read about end-of-file character, but as in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) say, EOF is system dependent.
What I want to know is what byte (or group of byte) I should keep away when write some method to encrypt file, on Windows or Linux? Thank!

Comment: Modern file systems don't use end-of-file markers. Encrypting a file to arbitrary binary data is fine, as long as you're able to decrypt it again.

Comment: A file is simply a sequence of bytes. There is no such thing as a terminator character. The closest thing to such a character is C's `getchar` function returning a negative value (typically -1) at the end of the file.

Comment: It sounds like you're developing your own encryption algorithm. That's fine for experimenting and study, but [never use such crypto for real work](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197).